# Invalid arguments passed in /app/public/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 150

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm getting that warning when I run my project in local way.

Carolina Spa Salon warning:

[image]

This is part of my code:

My header.php:

```
<div class="navegacion mt-3 py-1">
        <nav class="nav-principal navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded ">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#nav_principal" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Nav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-lg-none">Carolina Spa</a>
            <div class="container">                            
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'menu_class' => 'nav nav-justified flex-column flex-sm-row',
                        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id' => 'nav_principal',
                        'theme_location' => 'menu_principal'
                    );
                    wp_nav_menu($args);
                ?>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div><!--.navegacion-->
```

My functions.php:

```
<?php

// Cargar hojas de estilos
function carolinaspa_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.7.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Italianno|Lato:400,700,900|Raleway:400,700,900', array(), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap'), '1.0');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carolinaspa_styles');

// Setup Theme
function carolinaspa_setup() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu_principal' => esc_html__('Menu Principal', 'carolinaspa'),
        'social_menu' => esc_html__('Menu Social', 'carolinaspa')
    ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'carolinaspa_setup');

// Agrega la clase nav-item de bootstrap al <li> del menu_principal
function carolinaspa_li_class($classes, $item, $args) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($classes);
    echo "</pre>";
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'carolinaspa_li_class', 1, 3);
```

I need get my navbar by means of hooks with php, when I want to see the classes values, they dont show correctly.